# How to play video from input field in html

Tags: html, variables, video

I want create a page that allows a user to choose a video file from their local machine, and then have that video play on html. I have each separate portion figured out, but how do I get them to interact.

To get user input I have this:

```
<label for="input">Choose a video file to process:</label>

<input type="file"
       id="input" name="input_video"
       accept="video/mp4, video/mov">
```

and to play a video I have this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

How do I get whatever value is collected from the user input file path as a variable to be what is played by the second piece of code?

Thanks.

#### edit

My code now looks like this, but the video file player will not play the file I select.

```
<label for="input">Choose a video file to process:</label>


<script>document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var media = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
  var video = document.getElementById("video");
  video.src = media;
  video.style.display = "block";
  video.play();
});
</script>

<label for="input">Choose a video file to process:</label>
<input type="file" id="input" name="input_video" accept="video/mp4, video/mov">
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls style="display"></video>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the input's `change` event in javascript to get the file and then use `URL.createObjectURL` to create a temorary file to use as a src.

```js
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var media = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
  var video = document.getElementById("video");
  video.src = media;
  video.style.display = "block";
  video.play();
});
```

```html
<label for="input">Choose a video file to process:</label>
<input type="file" id="input" name="input_video" accept="video/mp4, video/mov">
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls style="display: none;"></video>
```

EDIT

Just remove the source element and add the media directly to the video element and then trigger the playing.

Comment: Thanks. I'm really new to html/js. What is the file structure for the two code elements? When I copy and paste your code into my `index.html` file then run in browser, the first code block just shows up as raw text. Should it be saved elsewhere? This is probably really basic...

Comment: @connor449 You would need to put it inside ```<script>//code//</script>``` tags

Comment: @connor449 It won't play the video, even though you can inspect the ```video``` element, copy the src, and paste it into the url bar of the window you created it in and it will play it. You might have to use the temporary file in a little bit different way, I'm trying to figure it out  :)

Comment: Thanks, the <script> tags worked perfectly. I am confused though, the file I select is not being played. Is the variable called `media`? How can I pass that into the video player?

Comment: @connor449, See my edited snippet in my answer. I'm not sure why, but it doesn't recognize the new ```src``` in the ```source``` element, so I edited it to just add the media src to the ```video``` element

Comment: When I run this, I am able to select a file but the video player never opens.

Comment: @connor449, You will need to use the updated javascript as well, I have it set up so it doesn't display the empty video element until a file is selected.

Comment: I am using the updated javascript and html. I select a video but nothing happens, just an empty video player.

Comment: I updated my post to reflect the total code I am using.

Comment: @connor449 It is an actual video that you can play in the video element if you add it's src to the video element manually? I'm not sure what's wrong because it works perfectly for me. Try hitting the code snippet button in my answer and selecting the video from there. I tried several .mp4 files in there and they worked perfect

Comment: @connor449, Aaaah, you will have to put the javascript AFTER the input tag. What is happening is the browser tries to find the input tag BEFORE it's even loaded. As a result, it throws an error (you would be able to see it in the console log) and stops the javascript and the ```change``` event never gets registered

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it es replacing the html of the video tag

html:

```
<video id="vp" autoplay muted loop controls>
    <source id="videoprev" src=""  type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#vp").html('<source src="'+URL.createObjectURL(file)+'" type="video/mp4"></source>');
```

In this case we take the src from an input file